# How do I show link image by using Python Flask jinja2?

Tags: python, flask, python-requests

This is the API homework by using NASA API. I used the jinja2 and showing the title, copyright, and other info successfully. However, for the image, I can't show the image but only the link (I try the HTML image formal but still not working). Maybe I shouldn't use jinja2 to display image? Is that another way to show the image? Thank you

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
import requests


app = Flask(__name__)
url = requests.get(
    'https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod?api_key=iBeT2hXG8tezilCqlJ5IXkNpTPWBFpB95bo72qyh')
text = url.json()
image = text['url']
name = text['copyright']
dt = text['date']
ti = text['title']
expl = text['explanation']

info = [{'title': ti,
         'name': name,
         'day': dt,
         'detail': expl,
         'image': image}]


@app.route('/')
@app.route("/home")
def home():
    return render_template('index.html', posts=info)


@app.route('/index', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def lionel():
    return render_template('index.html')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

```html
<title>NASA API</title>
  {% for info in posts %}
    <h1>{{ info.title }}</h1>
    <h2>by {{ info.name }}</h2>
    <h2>at {{ info.day }}</h2>
    <td>{{ info.image }}</td>
    <p>{{ info.detail }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: learn HTML - you have to use `<img src="{{ info.image }}">` to display image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use

```
 <img src="{{ info.image }}">
```

to display image.

---

Minimal working example. I use data directly from `response.json()` instead of creating new data.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template_string
import requests


app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def home():
    response = requests.get('https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod?api_key=iBeT2hXG8tezilCqlJ5IXkNpTPWBFpB95bo72qyh')
    info = response.json()

    return render_template_string('''<title>NASA API</title>
    <h1>{{ info.title }}</h1>
    <h2>by {{ info.copyright }}</h2>
    <h2>at {{ info.date }}</h2>
    <img src="{{ info.url }}">
    <p>{{ info.explanation }}</p>''', info=info)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: Thank you! You save my day! Thank you so much